# How to load js and css file in Spring MVC 3 with tiles3

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I am unable to load the Js and Css files in to jsp using Spring MVC 3 with tiles3. Can someone help me. Here the my configuration.

Project Folder Structure

```
-SpringWithTiles
----webapp
--------resouces
----------script
--------------js
---------------myscript.js
--------------css
---------------style.css
----WEB-INF
-------jsp
---------signIn.jsp
```

servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="viewResolver">  
    <property name="viewClass">  
    <value>  
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView  
    </value>  
     </property>  
</bean>  
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">  
  <property name="definitions">  
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/script/js/**"  location="/webapp/resources/script/css" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/script/css/**" location="/webapp/resources/script/js" />`
```

tiles.xml

```
 <tiles-definitions>  
   <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layout/simpleLayout.jsp">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp"/>  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>  
 <!--   <definition name="baseLayoutWithLeftPane" template="/jsp/layout 
/layoutWithLeftPane.jsp">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Learn - Educate" />  
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/layout/header.jsp" />  
       <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/jsp/layout/navigation.jsp" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/layout/footer.jsp" />  
  </definition>  
   <definition name="welcome" extends="baseLayoutWithLeftPane">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="Learn - Educate" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/home.jsp" />  
  </definition>   -->
  <definition name="siginIn" extends="baseLayout">  
       <put-attribute name="title" value="siginIn" />  
       <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/siginIn.jsp" />  
  </definition>
```

web.xml

```
      <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>babwitU</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

index.jsp

```
<a href="redirectToSiginIn">Click Here</a>
```

Contoller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/redirectToSiginIn")
public ModelAndView siginIn(){
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("/siginIn");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: the debug point is not reaching to controller request mapping method

Comment: Is this question anything to do with being able to load JS/CSS? It seems like you are saying the problem is when you click you sign-in link the controller is not being called? is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your response .. My problem get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In servlet.xml  change mapping like this  location="/resources/script/css"
and give path from resources/fileNameToLoad where you want to load ur js or css

In location attribute give path from /resources/** not from /webapps/

Answer (score 0):

The correct mapping should be:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/script/js/**"  location="/resources/script/css" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/script/css/**" location="/resources/script/js" />
```

The first `/` in the attribute `location` indicates the `${webappRoot}` already.

Comment: I tried your changes but not working, here the problem I am getting is whenever I clicked on link (in the indec.jsp) then the debug point is not reaching to its request mapping method in the controller.Do you have any idea why it is not comming.. please help me

Comment: Hi @BabuG, but on the `index.jsp`, the stylesheet and js files are loaded, right? if you click on a link, then it doesn't work, there are lots of possibility. you need to declare your problem with stacktrace another on another question.

Answer (score 0):

My problem get resolved with following configuration.. thanks for all

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>babwitU</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>babwitU</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/coreJava.xml,/WEB-INF/home.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>babwitU</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener> -->

</web-app>
```

**servelt.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.babwitU.life.dream.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />  
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <!-- <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" /> -->
    </bean>

<!-- <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="viewResolver">  
    <property name="viewClass">  
    <value>  
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView  
    </value>  
     </property>  
</bean>  
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">  
  <property name="definitions">  
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

     <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" />
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value ="redirectToSiginIn", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewSiginIn(){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("siginIn");
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value ="home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewHome(){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value ="java", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewJava(){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("java");
        return mav;
    }
```

**myjsp.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> <tiles:getAsString  name="title" ignore="true"></tiles:getAsString >
</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/js/appjs.js"></script>
 --><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/script/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

**folder structure**

```
  -springwithtiles
    ---webapp
    -----resources
    -------images
    ----------one.jpg
    -------script
    ------------style.css
    ------------myjs.js
    -----web-inf
    --------jsp
```